# Почему не отоброжается модель на HTML странице?

Tags: python, django

Вот сам код:

```html
{% block body %}
  <h1>{{listing.title}}</h1>
{% endblock body %}
```

При этом ничего не отоброжается, хотя когда обьявляю отдельную переменную для имени предмета все нормально:

```py
listing_title = listing.title
context = {'Listing': listing, 'listing_title': listing_title}
```

Comment: Во-вторых, у вас Listing в контексте с большой буквы, а в разметке - с маленькой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выглядит так, как будто переменная "listing" не определена в контексте. Это может быть причиной того, что данные не отображаются в HTML.

Чтобы это исправить, вам необходимо передать переменную "listing" в контекст. Попробуйте этот исправленный код:

```
listing_title = listing.title
context = {'listing': listing, 'listing_title': listing_title}
```

и по сути тот же код для HTML шаблона:

```
{% block body %}
  <h1>{{listing.title}}</h1>
{% endblock body %}
```